# how to add VB.NET language support to C# web api controller

Tags: c#, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have taken MVC-4, WEB API template for my project using C#. Now I have few controllers written in C#. Or I can say everything is written in C#. But now what I want is, I want to add web api controller using vb.net (vb) language.

So ultimately I want to have two types of controller (c# and vb) together. I don't want to use any other project for that. I want to add vb lang api controller in the same project.

I hope I'm clear with my requirements. How can I do this?

Comment: In .NET, you can have a VS solution which has multiple projects in different languages. You can not mix languages in same assembly or project, however.

Comment: I understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have VB and C# web api controller in same project. The language limitation of Visual Studio only allow you to use only one server side language in a project.

This is needed for compiler to identify what type of language need to be compile.

But you can have multiple project in a solution written in different language.